# Output a specific list using specific numbers, not consecutive numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Tell me please, what needs to be added in the code in order to call the matrix F[[1]] corresponding to x=5 in this way F[[5]] (or F[5]), and not in this way F[[1]] (Accordingly, for the seven). I can do it with loops, but it's probably can be do without them.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

Px[n1_, n2_, x_] := (n1^2 + n2)*x;

F = 
 ParallelTable[
  Table[Px[n1, n2, x], {n1, 0, 5}, {n2, 0, 5}], {x, {5, 7}}]

Out[327]= {{{0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25}, {5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30}, {20, 25, 
   30, 35, 40, 45}, {45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70}, {80, 85, 90, 95, 100, 
   105}, {125, 130, 135, 140, 145, 150}}, {{0, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35}, {7,
    14, 21, 28, 35, 42}, {28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63}, {63, 70, 77, 84, 
   91, 98}, {112, 119, 126, 133, 140, 147}, {175, 182, 189, 196, 203, 
   210}}}

F[[1]]

Out[329]= {{0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25}, {5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30}, {20, 25, 
  30, 35, 40, 45}, {45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70}, {80, 85, 90, 95, 100, 
  105}, {125, 130, 135, 140, 145, 150}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear[F]

(F[#1] = #2) & @@@ 
 ParallelTable[{x, Table[Px[n1, n2, x], {n1, 0, 5}, {n2, 0, 5}]}, {x, {5, 7}}];
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's important do it with ParallelTable. This way don't work with ParallelTable

Comment: I have fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, could you please rewrite it without using #, @ and &?

Comment: As @BobHanlon showed you in another question, you can use ``Hold[< unknown expression >] // FullForm`` to get the form without #, @, & ... However, I am kindly encouraging you to learn the usage of these symbols as they are quite common and useful in Mathematica code :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an explanation for @Mam mam about the # @ &.

first version is

```
Clear[G]

Table[{G[x] = Table[Px[n1, n2, x], {n1, 0, 5}, {n2, 0, 5}]}, {x, {5, 7}}];
```

But it needs to be ParallelTable. But Set and Parallel will have conflict. So first calculate then set.

```
data = ParallelTable[{x, Table[Px[n1, n2, x], {n1, 0, 5}, {n2, 0, 5}]}, {x, {5, 7}}];
```

Contains a list of pairs {a, b} which is F[a] = b; so we need to map them and set each pair to F.

If you don't want to see  # @ &,

```
set[a_,b_] := Set[F[a], b];
data // Map[set]
DownValues[F]
```

> {HoldPattern[F[5]] :> {{0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25}, {5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30}, {20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45}, {45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70}, {80, 85, 90, 95, 100, 105}, {125, 130, 135, 140, 145, 150}}, HoldPattern[F[7]] :> {{0, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35}, {7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42}, {28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63}, {63, 70, 77, 84, 91, 98}, {112, 119, 126, 133, 140, 147}, {175, 182, 189, 196, 203, 210}}}

Comment: Thanks for explanation!